# Form a firstname.lastname@domain.se address, eliminating diacritics from a name

Tags: java, beginner, strings, homework, swing

I'm an amateur programmer who just started learning programming, my school gave me an assignment to create code that reads a surname and lastname from an input dialog box and then to edit those name in the format of "surname.lastname@nackademin.se" all of wich should be in lowercase letters and only letters of a-z since in sweden we sometimes use "å,ä,ö" in our names.
I have managed to do so, as you can see below but i was wondering if there was a simpler way to do this (perhaps by using less code).

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Namn {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        char c = '.';
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ange namn och efternamn");
        s = s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim();
        s = s.replace(' ', c);
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        s = s.replace('å', 'a');
        s = s.replace('ä', 'a');
        s = s.replace('ö', 'o');
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s + "@nackademin.se");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can chain replaces and you don't need to replace "n. spaces" -> " ", you can just replace them with a "." if you trim first

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ange namn och efternamn");
s = s.trim()
      .replaceAll("\\s{2,}", ".")
      .toLowerCase()
      .replace('å', 'a')
      .replace('ä', 'a')
      .replace('ö', 'o');
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s + "@nackademin.se");
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Removing Diacritics:

Do not try and replace all the various diacritics like with separate replacements.

For UNICODE strings there is a idiomatic way to do it built in:

```
import static java.text.Normalizer.normalize;

System.out.println(normalize("å,ä,ö", Normalizer.Form.NFKD).replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", ""));
```

#### Outputs:

```
a,a,o
```

#### Note:

> This will not help transliterate stand alone characters like "ø" ( [LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH STROKE character (U+00F8)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00F8/index.htm) ).
>
> You will need to use an [actual transliteration mapping library](https://github.com/gcardone/junidecode) for stand alone characters like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the `null` object on your `showInputDialog()`.

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange namn och efternamn");
```

The signature that you're using is:

```
showInputDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message)
```

According to the [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html):

> Shows a question-message dialog requesting input from the user parented to parentComponent.

This simply means that the dialog would be displayed on top of the Component's frame. But since you are passing `null`, you can instead use:

```
showInputDialog(Object message)
```

> Shows a question-message dialog requesting input from the user. The dialog uses the default frame, which usually means it is centered on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

#### Name Parsing Edge Case:

Your whitespace handling is not generating what your requirements imply.

```
.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", "").trim().replace(' ', '.')
```

will not result in what you require if either the first name or the last name contain a space in the name.